# Trash Foods and Questions About It

Tags: tomodachi-life

What are trash foods and where do I get them? Can they come in the food store? Do the miis like it? I'm guessing they *don't* like it, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trash foods can't be bought from the food mart. They can only be obtained from the following:

- Having a Mii sell them at the morning market or as a random prize at the night market.
- Giving a Mii a frying pan and have it randomly "make" trash food.
- Have it spawn from the "Hunger" "Ritual", or "True Love" dreams.

[Source](http://tomodachi.wikia.com/wiki/Trash_food)

Answer (score 0):

I've heard about [trash foods](http://tomodachi.wikia.com/wiki/Trash_food) and pseudo-trashfoods on Wikia. Trash foods come in things like the following:

1. Morning Market
2. Night Market

and that's it, but PSEUDO-trash foods are the following:

(Remember that some of this might have come from other sources!)

1. Blue Cheese (OTHER SOURCE)
2. Green Juice ("testing")

OK, and that's it.

Comment: What do you mean by "other sources" and "testing"?

Comment: Other sources means things like wikia, and testing means by experience, I guess...

Comment: You guess? As in you don't know you were trying to say?